# Android login form submission not working

Tags: android, post, authentication, get, httpclient

So I'm working on an app that logs into my school's grade site, sending the URL encoded username and password form. The form data for a browser login is:

```
Database=10
LogOnDetails.UserName=yourusernamehere
LogOnDetails.Password=yourpasswordhere
```

I have edited my post to include my new code, which uses Apache's HttpClient.

I've been informed by Amit that the code 200 OK is an appropriate response, even though it returns 302 FOUND in my browser. So, I attempted a get request at url the site redirects users to, but I only get the login page contents.

EDIT: It works. I have no idea how, but it works. I've submitted my code as an answer. I know I had a very hard time getting here, so anyone who sees this is welcome to copy my code on their own.

Answer (score 0):

code() returns only the HTTP RESPONSE CODE, 200 means HTTP_OK that means your request was delivered successfully.

I assume you are expecting "302 FOUND" as the api response. then you should call `body()`.

Comment: body just returns the contents of the login page

Answer (score 0):

So I've managed to get it working. HttpRequest, HttpUrlConnection, etc were a mess. This works perfectly on android.

```
    public int login(){
    String loginsite = "https://home-access.cfisd.net/HomeAccess/Account/LogOn";
    String gradesite = "https://home-access.cfisd.net/HomeAccess/Classes/Classwork";
    String stud_ID = encryptor.land("student_id");
    String stud_pass = encryptor.land("student_password");
    HttpResponse response;
    int code =0;
    if(stud_ID==null || stud_pass == null || stud_ID.length()<7 || stud_pass.length()<1)
        return -1;
    try{
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        List<NameValuePair> nvp = new ArrayList<>();
        nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Database","10"));
        nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("LogOnDetails.UserName",stud_ID));
        nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("LogOnDetails.Password",stud_pass));
        code = sendPost(loginsite,nvp,client);
        System.out.println(getPageContent(gradesite,client));

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return -2;
    }
    return code;
}

private int sendPost(String url, List<NameValuePair> postParams, HttpClient client)
        throws Exception {

    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

    post.setHeader("Accept-Language","en-US,en;q=0.8");
    post.setHeader("Host", "home-access.cfisd.net");
    post.setHeader("Origin", "https://home-access.cfisd.net");
    post.setHeader("DNT","1");
    post.setHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
    post.setHeader("Accept","text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
    post.setHeader("cache-control","max-age=0");
    post.setHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
    post.setHeader("Referer", "https://home-access.cfisd.net/HomeAccess/Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=%2fHomeAccess%2f");
    post.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");


    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParams));

    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

    int responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

    System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Post parameters : " + postParams);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
    String line = "";
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        result.append(line+"\n");
    }
    return responseCode;
}

protected String getPageContent(String url,HttpClient client) throws Exception {

    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);

    get.addHeader("accept-language","en-US,en;q=0.8");
    get.addHeader("referer","https://home-access.cfisd.net/HomeAccess/Account/LogOn");
    get.addHeader("DNT","1");
    get.addHeader("connection","keep-alive");
    get.addHeader("content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    get.addHeader("cache-control","max-age=0");
    get.addHeader("Accept","text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
    get.addHeader("user-agent","Mozilla/5.0");

    HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
    int responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

    System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
    String line = "";
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        result.append(line+"\n");
    }

    return result.toString();

}
```